# Missing filter and sort criteria from views 

Tags: 7, views

I'm following along a [NodeOne video](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-5-filters) where it describes how to use the Views module. It looks like I'm missing a whole lot of filter criteria. Such as, all the "User:... " criteria, and the "Field:..." criteria is missing from the sort criteria menu.

This is a more or less fresh install of Drupal 7, and the only module I've installed is the views module, plus its dependencies.

How do I get those criteria to appear in the filter and sort menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running through that tutorial the other day too...

You need to add a relationship to the user (in the "Advanced" fieldset of your View), then the `User:` filters will appear.

I think the `Field:...` criteria are now called `Content:...`.

I got the tutorial content working fine in quite a short space of time and if memory serves these are the only things that were different from what was stated in the video. The video uses a beta/RC version of views whereas it's now in full release, so there will be a few differences.

Comment: Excellent, this got me the User: filters. That should do for now, I'll try and figure out the rest when I encounter it.